# Query posts via ajax with select element

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

So I have select element with 3 options: men, women, unisex. Whenever a user selects a new option, the posts should reload. I now have this as ajax function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select-gender').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl + "/woocommerce/archive-content.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {option: $(this).find("option:selected").val()},
            success: function(data){
                //adds the echoed response to our container
                $("#topdog").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the archive-content.php file:

```
<?php
function details($opt) {
  echo 'option: ' . $opt;
}

details($_POST['option']);

$selected = $_POST['option'];

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$args=array(
  'gender' => $selected,
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo 'List of manly product';
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

I realise now that just changing the $selected variable does not reload my posts. Should I load my posts in the 'data' part of the ajax function? How would I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry I donot completely understand your question So on change of select dropdowns you are looking to reload the select options or page. If it is page which page should the user be redirected to???

Comment: On change of selected options, (wordpress) posts get reloaded. The options in the dropdown are of a custom taxonomy, so different posts should get loaded

Comment: Can you please share url?

Comment: You don't need `$(this).find("option:selected").val()`. You should just be able to do `$(this).val()`. It will take the value based on the selection.

Comment: Also, presumably `ajaxurl` is defined somewhere not indicated on your script? If not, make sure that is defined.

Comment: `archive-content.php` must include the `wp-load.php` or `wp-config.php` file to access WordPress' functions/classes.

Comment: Also, for `'posts_per_page' => -1`, do you mean to do a negative 1?

Comment: -1 for posts_per_page is just to not set a limit. ajaxurl is defined. Must I loop through products with '$(this).val()' in the javascript? Or can I use the value to loop through the products somewhere else?